# how to get field type string from db model in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am doing the following:

```
model._meta.get_field('g').get_internal_type
```

Which returns the following:

```
<bound method URLField.get_internal_type of <django.db.models.fields.URLField: g>>
```

I only want the know that this field is "URLField" .  How do I extract that from this output?

*Note: I am doing this so that I can do validation on the fields. For example if a url , I want to check if it is well formed.*

Comment: Are you sure you're calling? It sounds like you're printing `a.model._meta.get_field('g').get_internal_type`

Comment: I am printing it.  I would like it to print URLField

Comment: from the Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/) Is this what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @crownedzero I am trying to get the type of the model field so that i can do some validation.  For example if a url, I want to validate it is well formed.

Comment: What is `a`, actually? I've just tried it in Django shell with my models and I do get the output like `Out[7]: u'CharField'`, and I've called `._meta.get_field('g').get_internal_type()` on model class directly

Comment: i removed it.  The model is all you need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get model field type for validation in django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20083764/how-to-get-model-field-type-for-validation-in-django)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you were doing this:

```
model._meta.get_field('g').get_internal_type()
```

You could not possibly get that as a result.

Instead, you are doing this:

```
model._meta.get_field('g').get_internal_type
```

Which, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20084085/908494), does not call the method, it just refers to the method as a bound method object. The return value is not part of that bound method object, it's created by the method when the method is called. So, you have to call it. So you need the parentheses.

Comment: Is there a way to get the `field type` of a model's foreignkey field?

Answer (score 14):

You can do this:

```
from django.db.models.fields import *
....
if model._meta.get_field('g').__class__ is UrlField:
    ....
....
```

or If you want to use String instead of working only with [UrlField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#urlfield)

```
....
if type(model._meta.get_field('g')) is eval('UrlField'):
    ....
....
```

or

```
isinstance(model._meta.get_field('g'), UrlField)
# This will return Boolean result
```

*You Can also use equal '==' instead of 'is'*

You can Check Offical Documentation for more information about

- [Model_meta](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/meta/)
- [Fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/)

Answer (score 6):

The answer is to call the method instead:

```
my_type = field.get_internal_type()
```

Comment: How may I access the field type of the related model's field / foreign key?