# how to get model field type for validation in django

Tags: django, django-models

I have tried:

```
field = model._meta.get_field_by_name(field_name)[0]
my_type = field.get_internal_type
```

This does not work as it gives back some bound method like:

```
<bound method URLField.get_internal_type of <django.db.models.fields.URLField:my_url>>
```

I want something I can world with like CharField, URLField, DoubleField, etc.

How can I get something like URLField so that I can validate if the url is well formed for example?

Comment: haven't you asked this recently? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081924/how-to-get-field-type-string-from-db-model-in-django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, if you want to call a function or method, you have to use parentheses around the arguments. If there are no arguments, you just use empty parentheses.

What you're doing is just referencing the method itself, not calling it.

Here's a simplified example:

```
>>> def foo():
...     return 3
>>> foo()
3
>>> foo
<function __main__.foo>
```

You can't "extract" the result from the function; you have to call it.*

So, in your example, just change the second line to this:

```
my_type = field.get_internal_type()
```

---

* OK, in this case, because the function just always returns a constant value, you could extract it by, e.g., pulling it from the source or the `func_code.co_consts` tuple. But obviously that won't work in general; if you want to get, say, the value of `datetime.now()`, it's not stored anywhere in the `now` method, it's generated on the fly when you *call* the method.