# how to extract value from bound method in python?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following code:

```
model =  MyModel()
field = model._meta.get_field_by_name('my_field')[0]
my_type = field.get_internal_type
print str(my_type)
```

This outputs:

```
<bound method URLField.get_internal_type of <django.db.models.fields.URLField: my_field>>
```

How can I extract the URLField type from the ubound method output?

Comment: Why not *call* the method, that method returns the internal type as a string..

Comment: Are you asking the exact same question as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081924/how-to-get-field-type-string-from-db-model-in-django#20081924) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20083764/how-to-get-model-field-type-for-validation-in-django), or are you asking something different? It's very hard to tell. If you're asking something different, make the difference clear. If you're asking the same thing, stop asking it over and over.

Comment: I'm asking something different @abarnert

Comment: @MartijnPieters what "the" method?

Comment: @Atma you're not calling the method here - `my_type = field.get_internal_type`, do it like this - `my_type = field.get_internal_type()`

Comment: OK, then _what_ is the difference?

Comment: @AlexParakhnevich: In the future, don't just post comments on answers saying that something is a duplicate, close the question (or, if you don't have enough rep, post a comment directly under the question suggesting that others do so).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Python 2.x, a bound method has three attributes:

- `im_func` is the function object.
- `im_class` is the class the method comes from.
- `im_self` is the `self` object the method is bound to.

So, just do this:

```
print my_type.im_self
```

---

In Python 3.x, `im_func` is renamed `__func__`, `im_self` is renamed `__self__`, and `im_class` is gone.

In 2.7, you can use the 3.x names in place of the 2.x names if you prefer.

---

The details of this are buried pretty deep in the documentation, but the [`inspect`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) module docs has a handy table giving you a brief explanation of what the most important special fields in the various built-in types do.

[This blog post](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-methods-work.html) has more detail, and if you want to know *why* it works like that, that's mostly documented in a few different posts on Guido's [History of Python](http://python-history.blogspot.com) blog between from March 2009 and June 2010.

Comment: He has the object right there; `field`, but the specific method, if called, returns a string representing the *field type*.. This is pretty Django specific, I suspect.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I'm not sure that's what he's asking. He wanted "the URLField type from the bound method". In other words, he wants the actual data behind the `<django.db.models.fields.URLField: my_field>` in the repr. Which is the `im_self`.

Comment: @abarnert, no, he wants just a return value.. proofs: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081924/how-to-get-field-type-string-from-db-model-in-django#20081924, 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20083764/how-to-get-model-field-type-for-validation-in-django. I really don't understand why he keeps duplicating this..

Answer (score 5):

Thanks @Martijn Pieters

The answer is to call the method instead:

```
my_type = field.get_internal_type()
```