# how to print field type of a field in django models

Tags: django, django-models

I have made a `Django` project and designed a model with a field name in it what I write is :

```
name = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
```

Is there a way to print CharField on the screen, using command like

```
d = name.field()
```

and it stores a String in variable `d` as `CharField`.
If I ask it as `attendance.field`, I want it to show `BooleanField` as output. Like :

```
from django.db import models as data_type
class UserAttendance(data_type.Model):
    user=data_type.ForeignKey(UserList,on_delete=data_type.CASCADE)
    date=data_type.DateField()
    attendance=data_type.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I searched but did not found anything that allowed to print `CharField` on screen. Can anyone suggest me how to do this ?

Comment: I just want it to return DataField  or BooleanField for date and attendance respectively

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get field type string from db model in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081924/how-to-get-field-type-string-from-db-model-in-django)

Comment: Format txt in proper manner and also highlighted important words to get easily what answer is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_internal_type() as suggested in the comment by @ruddra sir

```
UserAttendance._meta.get_field('attendance').get_internal_type()
```